# Change of variables, finding appropiate transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hi I'm working with a problem that asks me to find an appropiate transformation. The question is as follows: 
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9I5s.png)

It is clear for me that I can set $u=xy$, but how do I find $v$? I find it hard when there are two different equations, $y=\frac{x}{2}$ and $y=\frac{2}{x}$. I'd love an explanation!

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Please include the problem statement as text, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions, instead of linking to a picture of it. Your question is incomprehensible without that image, and so inaccessible to those who depend on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries. For more details, see [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10992/265466) to “How to ask a good question.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our region is bounded by:

$xy = 2\\
xy = 3\\
y= 2x\\
y = \frac 12 x$

Lets rewrite the last two equations:

$\frac {y}{x}= 2\\
\frac {y}{x} = \frac 12$

Then:

$u = xy\\
v = \frac {y}{x}\\
y = uv\\
x = \frac {u}{v}$

The Jacobian:

$\left|\begin{matrix}\frac {1}{v} & v\\-\frac {1}{v^2}& u \end{matrix}\right| = \frac {u+1}{v}\ du\ dv$

Comment: Can you take me through step by step how you get that y=2x is y/x=2? Same with y=0.5x? My brain is fried, done too much math today =)

Comment: if $y = 2x.$  Divide both sides by $x.$

Comment: Oh my god, I'm feeling so stupid now. But thank you so much for the help Doug, I appreciate it :D